# UV Mapping Doesn't Display in UV/Image_Editor

Tags: texturing, uv, unity

I've gone through tutorials and get the UV Mapping to work when testing on a simple block. However, when trying this on a bigger model, the UV Mapping won't display in the UV/Image_Editor. The Eiffel Tower model is all one mesh and I select Smart UV Project. Any suggestions.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @RayMairlot Sorry about that... I actually saw this post and was still having issues!

Comment: @user3356901 The render result is being displayed in the UV editor (even though there isn't one). Press the X next to the the box which says "render result" at the bottom of the image editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because at the bottom of the image editor, you are viewing the *render result*.  Click the X to the right of the image selection box or select another image and you should be able to see the unwrapped pelt.