# UV unwrapping of a row boat is not working

Tags: modeling, uv, uv-image-editor

I am almost new to blender and completely new to UV unwrapping.I have modeled a row boat following a tutorial on youtube. After completing the model, I am trying to unwrap it. But when I mark the seams and hit `U` to unwrap it.It shows nothing on UV/Image editor.I think I have done some serious mistake but can not figure it out.I have attached the blender file with marking all the seam: http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=49243

Comment: Do you select all before hititng U? Did you unlink Render Result image (probably empty if you haven't rendered anything) in the UV editor?

Comment: I have selected all of my model before hitting U.But, I didn't know how to unlink render result image.

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55539/why-does-the-uv-image-editor-remain-empty-after-uv-unwrapping and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16199/uv-mapping-doesnt-display-in-uv-image-editor?lq=1

Comment: Thanks Mr. Zak. I have unlinked the render result image and now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:
[image]

Change from Render Results to skiff-side.jpg

Comment: Instead of asking question in the answer please answer the question (even if you aren't exactly sure what's the problem in question). What is *skiff-side.jpg"? OP should unlink *any* image, and from your answer looks like *skiff-side.jpg* is a part of Blender which isn't.

Comment: Now, It is working.Why it's not working first time? and should I switch to skiff-side.jpg every time I have to unwrap?

Comment: Mr Zak I answered with "Change ...this by that". It's obvious that the jpg isn't part of blender. My answer works.